# Why does install4j lock all zip files in the installation directory?

Tags: install4j

My app used to have an update functionality that was working well for archives and not for installed app (access rights issues). I moved to install4J and now it is the reverse, the update works very well for installed app but not for archives.

For the archives, the updater download the new archive but does not offer to unzip it. Hence, I tried to put back my previous method for archives update but with no success. Here below a quick description of the process and the issue I am facing for the archives.

1. if the user check for new update and find one, the app download a file update.zip

2)a) the starting point of my app is Launcher.main(), if there is no update file, it calls App.main()

b) if there is update.zip file, it unzip the file, delete it and start App.main()

The issue is that the zip file is not deleted, it is locked by a process. I found out that I can create any zip file in the directory xxx.zip, launch my app and the zip file is reported as in used by my app. Why does install4J lock all the zip file? Can I prevent this?

Thank you in advance for your help

in case, it helps, the code and error raised are here:
https://github.com/akasolace/HO/blob/81e250534ed864ea84ab83ed167d519767f7bff3/src/main/java/core/HOLauncher.java#L39

Comment: Please show a screen shot of the "Java invocation" step of the launcher wizard.

Comment: @IngoKegel here it is https://snipboard.io/U0jd8e.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "Scan directory" entry with target "." will add all .jar and .zip files in the installation directory to the class path, so they will be locked by the JVM.

You would have to download your ZIP file to some other directory.

Comment: in my case I just changed the file extension to .piz but same idea really ...